# Yahoo forecastjson gives XML error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, yahoo-api

After browsing through this site, I found that you can get Yahoo weather in a JSON format using forecastjson.

When I run:

```
$.getJSON("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2112762724", function(data){
    ...
});
```

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2112762724. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've gotten this error before but its normally because I'm trying to load XML cross domain but this is clearly JSON.  If you go to the link in the getJSON function, it shows JSON data.  Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JSON` doesn't mean that you will not encounter cross domain problem. That is an object standard.

If you want to make a cross domain request, you should use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

The url that you are trying to request, doesn't support JSONP request. But you can use YQL instead of that.

here is an example,

```
var query = escape('select item from weather.forecast where woeid="2295424"');
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query + "&format=json&callback=c"; 

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});​
```

And here is the [URL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid=%222295424%22&format=json&callback=c) that you can check json result.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxfhh/1/)